# Isolating specific browser instance with SignalR

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

We are building an app which will send messages to the browser using SignalR. The user may have multiple browser instances open and we would like each message to be sent to the appropriate browser. Our understanding is that the <strike>ClientId</strike> ConnectionId would allow us to do this. The issue we're running into is accessing the <strike>ClientId</strike> ConnectionId, or SessionId, at the appropriate times in the codebase. Here's our scenario:

A MVC Action executes and, as part of that processing, a call to a Biztalk endpoint is made. The Biztalk execution is out of process (from the point of view of the MVC Action) and doesn't return when completed. This is by design. To notify the MVC application that it has completed, Biztalk sends a message to the MVC application's SignalR hub by calling the /myapp/signalr endpoint. The message is received by SignalR and then should be routed to the appropriate browser instance.

Since the message to SignalR is being sent by Biztalk, and not the MVC application, the ClientId of the connection to SignalR is not the one that identifies the browser instance that should receive the message. So what we are attempting to implement is somethign similar to the Return Address pattern by including the <strike>ClientId</strike> ConnectionId of the browser instance that initiates the Biztalk call in the message to Biztalk. When Biztalk sends its message to SignalR one of the contents is that original <strike>ClientId</strike> ConnectionId value. When SignalR processes the message from Biztalk it then can use the <strike>ClientId</strike> ConnectionId included in the message to route that message to the appropriate browser instance. (Yes we know that this won't work if the browser has been closed and re-opened and we're fine with that.)

The problem we face is that when initially sending the message to Biztalk from our MVC Action we cannot access the <strike>ClientId</strike> ConnectionId as it's only available in the Hub's Context. This is understandable since the MVC Action doesn't know which Hub context to look for.

What we have tried in it's place is to pass the SessionId through the Biztalk message and return it to SignalR. This solves the problem of including the browser instance identifier in the Biztalk message and returning it to SignalR. What it introduces is the fact that when a client connects to the Hub we cannot access the Session (and thus the SessionId) in the Hub's OnConnect method.

David Fowler posted a gist that reportedly shows how to make readonly SessionState accessible in a Hub but it doesn't work. (https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/4692934) As soon as we add this code into our application messages sent to SignalR cause a HTTP 500 error which is caused by SignalR throwing the following exception.

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.Parameter name: s]
System.IO.StringReader..ctor(String s) +10688601
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Json.JsonNetSerializer.Parse(String json, Type targetType) +77
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Json.JsonSerializerExtensions.Parse(IJsonSerializer serializer, String json) +184
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubRequestParser.Parse(String data) +101
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.OnReceived(IRequest request, String connectionId, String data) +143
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.<>c__DisplayClassc.<ProcessRequest>b__7() +96
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.<>c__DisplayClass3c.<FromMethod>b__3b() +41
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod(Func`1 func) +67
```

No matter the mode that we set SessionStateBehavior (as shown by David Fowler's gist) we either get this exception when sending a message to the Hub or SessionState is null when we are in the Hub's OnConnect.

So, after all that pre-amble, what we are asking is how do people update the appropriate client when working with this type of disconnected messaging in SignalR?

Comment: When you say ClientId do you mean Connection ID?

Comment: Yep. Updated to the right verbage

Comment: So there doesn't appear to be a technical solution to this. I think that the correct solution is to have a better architecture which doesn't rely on having return messages to the user. We're changing direction to head that way now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to send data to clients outside of a normal request to a hub then I'd recommend having a static Concurrent Dictionary on your hub that manages  your users and maps them to corresponding connection Id's.

With this approach you can send to any user at any point based on their mapped Connection Id.  Therefore when sending your data to Biztalk all you need to do is send your user id (created by you) and then when the data flows back to SignalR you can lookup the ConnectionId (if one exists) for that given user id.

Lastly, you can manage your user mappings by adding users to your concurrent dictionary in OnConnected, adding only if they are not there in OnReconnected, and removing in OnDisconnected.

Comment: The problem is that when the user has multiple instances of the app/page open simply sending the user id to BizTalk isn't enough to completely identify the browser instance that the returning message should be sent to. 

For example, Joe has two browser instances open with ClientIds 123456ABC and DEF987654. If all we send to BizTalk (and it returns to us) is "Joe" then we don't know which browser instance to push the message to.

Comment: What we need is to be able to take a unique browser identifier (which I think ClientId is the answer to) and send it to Biztalk so it can be returned in the Biztalk message. With the message being sent to Biztalk outside of the Hub and Context we don't have any access to ClientId...so what is the alternative becomes the question.

Comment: You can still accomplish that by mapping users to connection ID's in your hub.  For instance instead of it being a user -> connection ID mapping it could be a user -> browser[] mapping where browser has a unique id that is mapped to a connection ID.  At this point you just need to send the browserID to biztalk and then you can look it up when it gets back to the SignalR endpoint.  All the while the browser ID's are still managed by OnConnected, OnReconnected, OnDisconnected etc.

Comment: Right. We tried that approach and the only logical item we could think of is the SessionId since we need to be able to support multiple tabs as well as multiple browser instances. Unfortunately, as I outlined in the question, the one technique to access SessionState and SessionId inside OnConnect (which is where we would need to do the mapping) continually fails. If you know of a different value that is accessible in the Hub that we can use to map browser/tab instances we'd love to hear about it.